# how to link it correctly?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In my web page I have a link in menu like this

```
<a href="system/home">Home</a>
```

The correct page for this is `localhost:8080/mySite/system/home`

Now the problem is when I am on some other page like
`localhost:8080/mySite/system/users/create`

and try to click Home link it points me to

```
localhost:8080/system/users/system/home
```

which is wrong. I can I always point it correctly where the page is currently open?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204870/java-jsp-how-to-get-domain-url-web-application-name

Answer (score 0):

Use the url tag

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:url var="home" value="/system/home"/>

<a href="${home}">
```