# How to avoid hard-coding the application context path in js/ajax scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I use **Spring MVC** and **Javascript/ajax**. **I have an issue with the way my ajax scripts refer to a server-side resource.**

Say I have **two pages** that need to use **the same server-side resource** through ajax:

The url for the first page is:

- `/myapp/advertisement/28/edit`
- `/myapp/signup`

Say the server-side resource that my ajax script need to use is:

- `/myapp/geolocation/addressAutocomplete`

As of now, I have **hard-coded** the application context path i.e. **`/myapp`** in my ajax script.

**If and when my application context path changes I need to update is all over my scripts.**

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the HTML page that includes the script you could put an HTML `base` tag that points to the context.  See the answer to [How to get domain URL and application name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204870/java-jsp-how-to-get-domain-url-web-application-name)

And you can read about the `base` tag at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp which states `The <base> tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.`

Before deciding whether or not to use this tag, it may be worth reading answers to [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`$.ajaxPrefilter()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) to prepend context path to all jQuery AJAX requests.

It can be configured in `<script>` element of your pages, where context path value is available (e.g. `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in JSP).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a JSP page using an AJAX request within an external JS file, I solved the problem by using a hidden field in JSP containing the contextPath:

```
<input type="hidden" id="contextPath" value="<%=request.getContextPath()%>" readonly></input>
```

In JS file, get the value of the hidden field:

```
var contextPath = $('#contextPath').val();
```

Finally, make the request call by concatenating the context path and the relative url like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: contextPath + '/home/reporting',
        success: function(data) {
                    }
       });
```

Hope this help anyone facing the same issue