# How to get URL content in Java application

Tags: java, url, browser

Im currently working in a project where i have to detect the url entered in the browser and read its content from a java application.

There are plenty of examples out there to show how the content is captured if the URL is given to the app. But in my scenario I have to capture the URL from the browser.

Any examples I can refer? Im totally new to java but i do have experience in c#.

Comment: What about web site crawling?

Comment: one collegeue asked me to use JnetpCap to read the packets and decompese. But as I mentioned Im new to java Im kind of lost..

Comment: @subodh : this is a windows application. I need to capture the URL from that application to read the content.

Comment: Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204870/java-jsp-how-to-get-domain-url-web-application-name

Comment: Definitely you will put your url in somewhere(Textfield or text area) of your windows application, read the url from that field and make a call of crawler to get the website contents.

Comment: @peeskillet I went through that. It is about a web application i guess.

Comment: @subodh this is kind of a service.. so I cant let the user to enter any input. have to capture it from the browser.

Comment: Why not consider writing an HTTP Proxy in Java, and configuring the browser to use your application as its proxy?