# Image not loading in chrome but works fine in eclipse inbuilt browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, eclipse, jsp

I am building a dynamic web application using eclipse javaEE . I am adding a background image to a jsp page by body tag attribute background().When I run this program in eclipse inbuilt browser image loads completely fine but when I run the same program on chrome , background image doesn't load.
Please help in rectifying this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: background is a not a function.Instead it is a css property & to use it inline with the element you have to use the style attribute.

Comment: no,background is the attribute of body tag in html. body background="C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png"

Comment: What? You're 'serving' a local static file, quite obvious that won't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did face exact same issue **INDRESH KHANDELWAL** faced in my **JAVA** project.

Images weren't loading in any browser and I got this **error message**:

> *Not allowed to load local resource:*

But works fine in **eclipse IDE**.
So I used this logic to solve this problem. Upload your image path into **Database** and fetch from there whenever you need the image.
Below is the code that I used for simple **login page** with background image,

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>

<html>
<head>

    <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cart_db","root","toor"); 
    Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
    String sql = "select * from img_table where id = 'login_bgimg'";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    String s1 = "";
    if(rs.next())
    {   
        s1=rs.getString(2); // Image URL
    %>
     <title> Login </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login_style.css">
 </head>
 <body background = "<%=s1%>" >
     <div class="signin">
         <form action="LoginCode.jsp" method="post">
             <h2>Sign In</h2>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name = "txtUserName">
             <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name = "txtPWD">
             <button class = "btn">Sign In</button> <br>
             <a href="#">Forget Password?</a> | 
             <a href="#">Create an Account</a> | 
             <a href="#">Back to Home</a>
         </form>
     </div>
   <% 
   }    
   %>

 </body>
</html>
```

**Disclaimer:** All, I am not an expert. I just posted what seems to be working for me. If there is a better way to handle it, please do post it here. It will be useful to me and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in your css file

```
body {
    background-image: url("<image>");

}
```

or add as inline to body tag

```
style="background-image: url("image");"
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: <body background="C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png">

<div class="home"><a href="InitialPage.jsp"><img src="\src\background.png"></img></a></div>
<form>
  <div class="employee">
  <a href="Login.jsp"><button type="button" name="employee">Employee</button></a></div>
  <br />
  <br /><div class="admin">
  <a href="Adminloginportal.jsp"><button type="button" name="admin" >Admin</button></a></div>
 </form> 
</body>
</html> This is working fine in eclipse inbuilt browser but the background is not visible when I tried to access the same url on chrome...

Comment: try inline style as <body style=""background-image: url("C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png");"">.Hope this works

Comment: replace background attribute with the mentioned inline styling that will fix the issue for you.

Comment: Still its working fine on eclipse but background image doesn't load in chrome. When I googled this problem ,it has do something with context path and relative path?

Comment: Could you please rightclick on the body of the page and click inspect element and select console and check if you are seeing any error?

Comment: I am working in eclipse.Its shows no error in the console.

Comment: try replacing backward "\" with forward "/" in the image URL

Comment: <body style="background-image:url('C:/Users/Nagasai/Desktop/AngularJs/paper.gif')"> sample which i have tried in my local and working fine in chrome

Comment: no, still not showing background in chrome.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869196/img-tag-image-not-loading-in-chrome.    This is another article related to my problem,but I do not understand it .

Comment: In Chrome , please click Ctrl+Shift+J and share the screenshot once to check the error and paste the HTML code once using background-image

Comment: the error here showing is:Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/indresh/Desktop/background.png                                                              <body background="C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png">


<form>
  <div class="employee">
  <a href="Login.jsp"><button type="button" name="employee">Employee</button></a></div>
  <br />
  <br /><div class="admin">
  <a href="Adminloginportal.jsp"><button type="button" name="admin" >Admin</button></a></div>
 </form> 
</body>

Comment: for testing ,could you please try with using <body style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif');">

Comment: For eclipse to resolve, Could you please try placing that image in you workspace project folder under images folder and use background-image: url('images/background.png')

Comment: That works fine Thanks.. I have created a folder under webcontent in my project called images then I kept my image in that folder and just called /images/background.png in the background tag in body.

Answer (score 0):

background is attribute;not a function.  so remove '()' characters next to background attribute

Comment: <body background="C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png">

<form>
  <div class="employee">
  <a href="Login.jsp"><button type="button" name="employee">Employee</button></a></div>
  <br />
  <br /><div class="admin">
  <a href="Adminloginportal.jsp"><button type="button" name="admin" >Admin</button></a></div>
 </form> 
</body>
</html> This is what I am doing and its working fine when I opened in it eclipse inbuilt browser but the background is not visible when I tried to access same url on chrome..

Comment: Image resource should be relative to the Web project rather than abstract path. For e.g. keep image in 'WebContent' path and change resource as  background="background.png"

Answer (score 0):

in HTML5 some atributes are deprecated
you try use this in the css file
body {
    background: url("image");

}

Answer (score 0):

Rather then putting `Absolute-Path` copy past that image into `WebContent` and then give the path from the class path

Now, Assume that you have your Background.png in `WebContent` then write CSS as below...

```
body {
    background-image: url("Background.png");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're trying to server a local static file `C:\Users\indresh\Desktop\background.png`.

That obviously won't work, as your browser doesn't (and shouldn't) have access to your local filesystem without any prefixes, but to a specific server-hosted directory, in which all your web-hosted files should be.

E.g. in a xampp-apache enviorment you'd have - as standard - a hosted directory like that: `C:\xampp\htdocs`. All files in this directory are reachable trough your apache web-server, as standard via `localhost/...`.

If you place a HTML-File and a image in this folder you may access them both relatively.

Very basic example:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your HTML..</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="image.png">
</body>
</html>
```

**C:\xampp\htdocs\image.png**

Any picture you'd want to serve..