# Spring MVC: redirect user according to browser language

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, http-accept-language

In **Spring MVC** 4 how can I **redirect the user** to a localized url according to the **browser language** (the HTTP header "Accept-Language")?

I would that if an user is trying to access the url `example.com/some/path` it will redirect to `de.example.com/some/path` if its browser language is "DE" (i.e. the "Accept-Language" header is set to "de").

In the same way, if an user is accessing `de.example.com/some/path` and its language is EN it should be redirected to `example.com/some/path`.

What is the easiest way to get that?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this in your controller:

```java
@RequestMapping("/path")
public String someMapping(Locale locale) {
    if ("de".equals(locale.getLanguage())) {
        return "redirect:http://de.example.com/some/path";
    }
}
```

Note that language codes are written in lowercase.

Comment: You'd need to put that in every controller, in case they didn't arrive at /path

Comment: Yes, maybe I did not specify that "some/path" is **any** path in my web site, and as @NeilMcGuigan said I'd need to put that in each controller (and I would avoid this).. Moreover it does not seem to handle even the reverse case (from de.example.com to example.com)....

Answer (score 1):

Create a HandlerInterceptor (extend [HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html)) and get the Accept-Language header from the Request. You need to register your Interceptor in your Web Application Context Config.

You also want to know what domain your server is running on. See [How to get domain URL and application name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204870/how-to-get-domain-url-and-application-name)

You should allow the user to change their locale (they might want your site in German even if browser is set to en_US). So you'd need to set a cookie in this case. See [LocaleChangeInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) too.

Comment: Thanks for references.. It all seems a bit complex (I thought there was an easier way), but now I try!