# Grails 2.5.6 createLink does not take into account whether the application is on HTTPS server or not?

Tags: grails

I have application which is being accessed in 3 different ways
1. client's internel ip which is only accessible from his machines,
2. client's external ip which is only accessible to use on our vpn server.
3. client's secure domain name which is also only accessible to his intranet.

Issue is that website when being accessed from HTTPS URL is not generating correct link starting from https rather generates link starting from http.

As a result, the AJAX call fails because of web security restrictions which prevents http calls from https server.

IP addresses works fine for now.
I tried using grails.severURL to explicitly mention the https url it works for https url but that breaks the website functionality on IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createLink bases its absolute url on the setting grails.serverURL that you specify in the Config.groovy file of your application.

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.6/ref/Tags/createLink.html

it says :

> absolute (optional) - If true will prefix the link target address with
>   the value of the grails.serverURL property from Config.groovy, or
>   http://localhost: if there is no setting in Config.groovy and
>   not running in production.

Then if you do not want to use grails.serverURL you have to change your code in your gsp.
You should generate a relative path with createLink as for example :

```
// generates "/shop/book/list"
<g:createLink controller="book" action="list" />
```

add the parameter absolue='false' if it keeps on generating absolute url

Then you can pass this kind of url to your ajax call it should work it should work if you're using jquery for your call.

But if you want to use an absolute url in your code then you should combine a relative path from createLink with another trick :

```
<g:set var="url" value="${request.requestURL}" />
<g:set var="uri" value="${request.requestURI}" />
<g:set var="yourUrlForAjaxCall">${url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length())}${request.contextPath}${createLink(action: 'list', controller: 'book')}</g:set>
```

Then the variable yourUrlForAjaxCall gives what you need.

My answer is based on BalusC answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206865/592477)